# Sapui5 CustomTreeItem How can i add an item to the tree Structure

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Im facing an issue in [CustomTreeItem](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.m.CustomTreeItem). Im able to display the tree structure from JSON Successfully. But im facing an issue to add the Data manually on Click of Add Button.

[image]

If you see the above image if i hit on **+** Button i need to add one Tile in the below. But im able not able to add and im not seeing any error in the console too..
Below is my code...

XML
====`

```
<Tree items="{selModel>/}" id="Tree" class="sapUiTinyMarginTop tilesClass selTree">
                                    <CustomTreeItem id="treeItem" detailPress="pressCustomTreeItem">
                                        <VBox class="customSelTile" id="customSelTile">
                                            <HBox>
                                                <VBox class="sapUiTinyMarginTop customTxts">
                                                    <Label class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin headTxtFont" text="{selModel>text}"/>
                                                    <Label class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin subHeadTxtFont" text="{selModel>subheader}"/>
                                                </VBox>
                                                <Button class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop" press="addTile" icon="sap-icon://add"/>
                                                <Button class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop" press="removeTile" icon="sap-icon://less"/>
                                            </HBox>
                                        </VBox>
                                    </CustomTreeItem>
                                </Tree>
```

`

## Controller ::

```
var selOrgJson = [{
            "text": "Department",
            "subheader": "Production Management JP",
            "personName":"Kuwahara Atushi",
            "nodes": [{
                "text": "Department",
                "subheader": "Production JP",
                "personName":"Kawasaki Takeshi"
            }, {
                "text": "Department",
                "subheader": "Planning Scheduling JP",
                "personName":"Fukuyama Sumire",
                "nodes": [{
                    "text": "Department",
                    "subheader": "Planning Operations",
                    "personName":"Sakata Junko"
                }]
            }, {
                "text": "Department",
                "subheader": "Sales Office, North East Japan",
                "personName":"Emoto Hloronori"
            }, {
                "text": "Department",
                "subheader": "Sales Office, South East Japan",
                "personName":"Suzuki Aya"
            }, {
                "text": "Department",
                "subheader": "Partner Sales JP",
                "personName":"Kuwahara Atushi"
            }]
        }];

        var selModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        selModel.setData(selOrgJson);
        this.getView().setModel(selModel, "selModel");

addTile: function (oEvt) {
        var vBox = new sap.m.VBox();
        vBox.addStyleClass("customSelTile");
        var hBox = new sap.m.HBox();
        var insideVBox = new sap.m.VBox();
        insideVBox.addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMarginTop customTxts");
        var headInput = new sap.m.Input({
            type: "Text"
        });
        var subInput = new sap.m.Input({
            type: "Text"
        });
        insideVBox.addItem(headInput);
        insideVBox.addItem(subInput);
        hBox.addItem(insideVBox);
        vBox.addItem(hBox);
        var button1 = new sap.m.Button({
            press: this.addTile,
            icon: "sap-icon://add"
        });
        var button2 = new sap.m.Button({
            press: this.removeTile,
            icon: "sap-icon://less"
        });
        hBox.addItem(button1);
        hBox.addItem(button2);
        vBox.addItem(hBox);

    },
```

Can some one please help how can i add a tile on Click of Add button to the **CustomTreeItem**. If my above approach is wrong in controller means then Please help me with some alternate solution .

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue with below piece of code..

```
addTile: function (oEvt) {

        var _oItem = oEvt.getSource().getParent().getParent().getParent();
        var _sBindingPath = _oItem.getBindingContextPath();
        var _oModel = this.getView().getModel("selModel");
        var aData = _oModel.getProperty(_sBindingPath);
        var _oChildNodes = [];
        if (aData.nodes !== undefined) {
            _oChildNodes = aData.nodes;
        } else {
            aData.nodes = _oChildNodes;
        }

        var newData = {
            "text": "",
            "subheader": ""
       }
```

Thank you